# timeout em AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Estou fazendo um aplicativo em ionic, que usa Angular.js como base. Tenho uma splash nativo do ionic com 3s e logo depois entra no controller splash que tem um vídeo de 5s com uma animação. Queria saber como fazer um redirecionamento para um outro controller, login assim que o video acabar.
Alguém pode me ajudar nisso?

Answer (score 2):

Pra fazer o que queres, sempre que a aplicação iniciar você redirecionar a rota para uma tela qualquer, para isso, faça um state go no run:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(something => {})
  .run(function ($state) {
    $state.go('rotaDaTelaComVideo');
  });
```

De acordo com a documentação do Angular: [Documentação](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/ce669edfa14dc7eb7c389d2f82c9c98399a9009b/docs/content/guide/module.ngdoc)

1. `config` é chamado primeiramente na inicialização do módulo.
2. `run` é chamado uma vez na inicialização do módulo, logo após o config.
3. Compilação de diretivas e outros...
4. Controllers são criados.
5. Link das Diretivas, se houver.

Dessa maneira, é seguro chamar uma rota no run, de meneira que na próxima iteração do Angular ele irá carregar seu módulo.

**Bonus**:

Ainda, se você quer que o vídeo rode apenas uma vez, você pode salvar uma flag no localStorage:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .config(something => {})
  .run(function ($state, $window) {
    if ($window.localStorage['alreadyShown'] !== true) {
      $state.go('rotaDaTelaComVideo');
      $window.localStorage['alreadyShown'] = true;
    }
  });
```

Assim ele irá rodar apenas a primeira vez que o usuário iniciar o aplicativo, ou depois de limpar todos os dados do cache.

Comment: Bem vindo a comunidade stackoverlow em português. Muito boa sua resposta :)

Answer (score 0):

Injete o `$state` ao seu Controller e depois que o vídeo terminar use o `$state.go`.

```
function goLogin(){
$state.go("app.login-new");
}
```

Comment: como colocar isso em código? digo, depois que vídeo acabar

Comment: Coloca o trecho de código que você manipula o vídeo pra vê se consigo te ajudar

Comment: [Aqui tem uma maneira](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/b60djmho/22/). Veja na linha 80, o redirecionamento.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-view title="splash" id="splash" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header vcenter" scroll="false">
<video preload="metadata" autoplay="autoplay" webkit-playsinline="webkit-playsinline" class="videoPlayer">
  <source src="video/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Controller

```
.controller('splash', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 
function ($scope, $stateParams) {


}])
```